# The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (EF installed)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS 2012. I installed with Nuget the `EntityFramework` (version 6.1.1), and add references to the `System.Data` and `System.Data.Entity`, but when I open a new class in the solution and refering to DbContext, it says:

> "The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

It's weird beacuse the DbContext is green, like every recognized class, when I press F12 to look into the DbContext class it brings me to the `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` class as it should be.

```
public DbContext MyContex { get; set; }
```

The same happanes with DbSet

```
public DbSet<TEntity> MySet { get; set; }
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: It may sound stupid, but try to clean your solution and rebuild it, or even restart VS. You never know.

Comment: Is this your only compiler error? If there are other errors, try dealing with them first and see if you still get this one.

Comment: Also, you say you got System.Data and System.Data.Entity - looks like the latest EntityFramework NuGet package should include EntityFramework.dll, but not System.Data.Entity.dll. You may need to clean up your references and pull the NuGet package again.

Comment: EF6 added some breaking changes. It is now completely out of band and contained in the EntityFramework assembly. You should not be using System.Data.Entity any more.

Comment: **Yorye Nathan**- not stupid at all, I tried that but it's still not working. **Joe Enos**- no other errors, just those two and another one related "MyClass<TEntity>.DbContext' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'". **Joe Enos** \ **Dismissile**- when I removed the Data and the Data.Entity the classes are not recognized at all.

Answer (score 5):

Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0

Comment: it works, I used Install-Package EntityFramework -version 6.1.3 to work with VS 2015

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the project was compiled with Target Framework 3.5, when I changed it to 4.5 it worked. Thank you all for you comments.

Comment: You sir.. are a star.

Answer (score 2):

using System.Data.Entity;

// this will solve both the **DbContext** and **DbSet** errors

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried referencing EntityFramework.dll instead? Or maybe you can try the fully qualified name " public System.Data.Entity.DbContext MyContex { get; set; } ".

Comment: when typing "Using EntityFramework" it said it doen't exist. Putting System.Data.Entity.DbContext gets me the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

The Issue occurs mainly when you change the version of your .Net solution.I solved the issue by

Adding the Dll **EntityFramework.dll** if you are using EntityFramework Version 6

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if it is a too late response: I was having the same issue today with VS2015. Anyway, fully qualified name will do the job,

> public class StudentEntities : System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error after upgrading from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017. I closed VS, deleted my .suo file, restarted VS, rebuilt the solution, and everything works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding a new project to an existing solution and ran into the same problem. I used Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution... and I was able to see the versions that all the other projects use. That way, I was able to pick the same version for my project that was used throughout the rest of the soution.